# How to join two or more external .tex file using another .tex file and then compile?

Tags: external-files, input

Suppose I have two tex files `file1.tex` and `file2.tex`. I want to join them in another tex file. I have tried to do this with the following one :

```
\documentclass{book}  
\begin{document}  
\chapter{Chapter-1}  
\section{Section-1}
\begin{theorem}
Theorem 1.1.1
\end{theorem}

\input{file1}
\input{file2}


\begin{lemma}
Lemma   
\end{lemma}
\end{document}
```

But this shows error. Is it possible to do so ?

file1.tex is given below  :
\input{mks}

```
\begin{document}





\begin{center}
{\textbf{\huge{Abstract Algebra}}}
\end{center}


\noindent\large{\textbf{Part-B}}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item Consider a group  $G$. Let $Z(G)$ be its centre. i.e.,$Z(G)=\{g \in G : gh=hg \mbox{~for all~} h \in G\}$. For $n \in \mathbf{N}$, the set of
 positive integers , define $J_n=\{(g_1,\dots,g_n)\in Z(G)\times \dots \times Z(G) : g_1\dots g_n=e\}.$ As a subset of the  direct product group 
$G\times \dots \times G$($n$ times direct product of the group $G$), $J_n$ is 
\begin{enumerate}
 \item not necessarily a subgroup.
\item a subgroup but not necessarily a normal subgroup.
\item a normal subgroup.
\item isomorphic to the direct product $Z(G)\times \dots \times Z(G)$($(n-1)$ times).
\end{enumerate}


 \item Let $G$ be a group of order $77$. Then the center of $G$ is isomorphic to
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\begin{multicols}{4}
 \item $\mathbf{Z}_{(1)}$
\item $\mathbf{Z}_{(7)}$
\item $\mathbf{Z}_{(11)}$
\item $\mathbf{Z}_{(77)}$
\end{multicols}
\end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}




\end{document}
```

where mks.tex is :

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb,graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage[margin=0.45in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rank }{rank }
\DeclareMathOperator{\trace }{trace }
\DeclareMathOperator{\lcm }{lcm }
\DeclareMathOperator{\nullity }{nullity }  

 and file2.tex is :  


\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=.5in]{geometry} 

\usepackage{amsthm,xypic,graphicx}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{example}{Example}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}

\begin{document}
\markboth{Right}{Left}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{Section 1.1}
\begin{theorem}
 Theorem
\end{theorem}
\begin{lemma}
 lemma1
\end{lemma}

\begin{theorem}
 Theorem
\end{theorem}














$$
\xymatrix{& S\ar@{-}[ld]\ar@{-}[rd] &\\
\{0,a,b,s\}\ar@{-}[d] & &\{0,c\}\ar@{-}[ldd]\\
\{0,a\}\ar@{-}[rd] & & \\
& \{0\} &
}
$$
\begin{center}
 figure A.1 : chosen subsets of $S$ see book b119
\end{center}



$$
\xymatrix{ h_{C}(C) \ar[r]^{\eta(C)}\ar[d]^{h_C(f)} & T(C)\ar[d]^{T(f)} \\
h_C(X)\ar[r]^{\eta(X)} & T(X) 
}
$$
\begin{center}
 figure B.1 : commutativity of the rectangle
\end{center}


$$
\xymatrix{(h_C,T)\ar[rr]^{\theta= \theta_{C,T}}\ar[d]^{N_*(\alpha)} & & T(C)\ar[d]^{\alpha(C)}\\
(h_C,S)\ar[rr] & & S(C)
}
$$
\begin{center}
 figure B.3 : commutativity of the rectangle
\end{center}



$$
\xymatrix{(h_C,T)\ar[rr]^{\theta_C= \theta_{C,T}}\ar[d]^{N_*(f)} & & T(C)\ar[d]^{T(f)}\\
(h_D,T)\ar[rr]^{\theta_D=\theta{D,T}} & & T(D)
}
$$
\begin{center}
 figure B.4 : commutativity of the rectangle
\end{center}



$$
\xymatrix{h_C(C)\ar[r]^{\eta_{(C)}}\ar[d]^{h_C(f)} & & T(C)\ar[d]^{T(f)}\\
h_C(D)\ar[rr]^{\eta_{(D)}} & & T(D)
}
$$
\begin{center}
 figure B.5 : commutativity of the rectangle
\end{center}





$$
\xymatrix{A(U)\ar[rr]^{h(U)}\ar[d]^{r_{_{V,U}}} & & B(U)\ar[d]^{T_{U,V}}\\
A(V)\ar[rr]^{h(V)} & & B(V)
}
$$
\begin{center}
 figure B.6 : commutativity of the rectangle
\end{center}




\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you be more precise? What is the code in `file1` and `file2` ? What are the errors?

Comment: @PaulPichaureau I have updated my post with two files.

Comment: It would be helpful if you reduced this to a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228).  Can the same problem not be reproduced with a subset of these files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend [the `standalone` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/standalone):

[image]

### Notes:

- [The `geometry` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/geometry) was used to change the `paperheight` so as to make it easier to show an image here.
- The color was used to make it easier to see the content fro the different files.
- [The `filecontents` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/filecontents) was used to package the separate files into one [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228) .

## Code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[paperheight=12.0cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{file1.tex}
    \documentclass{book}
    \begin{document}\color{blue}  
        \chapter{Chapter-1}  
        \section{Section-1}
        Text from File 1.
    \end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{file2.tex}
    \documentclass{book} 
    \begin{document}  \color{red}
        \chapter{Chapter-1}  
        \section{Section-1}
        Text from file 2.
    \end{document}
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
\input{file1}
\input{file2}

\color{brown}
\chapter{Main File}
Text in main file.
\end{document}
```

Comment: this shows an error : "'standalone.sty' not found.\usepackage". I don't know what is this!

Comment: @SoumitraSen: You must be running a really old release (2009 perhaps?). I'd recommend you update to something more recent such as TeXLive2012.

Comment: Please, tell me one way so that I can update. I am using 'kile. on 'ubuntu10.04'. Thank you.

Comment: @SoumitraSen: That should be a separate question. But I would recommend you install [TexLive 2012](http://www.tug.org/texlive/).

Comment: Each of the sub files cannot be compiled separately if it doesn't load `xcolor`.

Answer (score 6):

As a best practice, I arrange your scenario as follow to be more general. You have:

- a package `mypackage.sty` in which you put all packages used in both main input file and sub files (child files).

  ```
  % mypackage.sty
  \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01] 
  \ProvidesPackage{mypackage}[2013/05/01 v0.01 LaTeX package for my own purpose]
  \RequirePackage{amsmath}
  % put other packages here
  \endinput
  ```
- the first input file `input1.tex` as a sub file (child file) as follows. It loads `mypackage.sty` package.

  ```
  % input1.tex
  \documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
  \usepackage{mypackage}
  \begin{document}
  Karl's students do not care about arrow tips.
  \[
  E \ne mc^2
  \]
  \end{document}
  ```
- the second input file `input2.tex` as a sub file as follows. It also imports `mypackage.sty` package.

  ```
  % input2.tex
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{mypackage}
  \begin{document}
  Karl's students do not care about dashing patterns.
  \[
  pV = nRT
  \]
  \end{document}
  ```
- the main input file `main.tex` as follows. It must load `mypackage.sty` and `docmute` packages. `docmute` package is used to import all stuffs (of the imported sub files) inside `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.

  ```
  % main.tex
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{mypackage}
  \usepackage{docmute}

  \begin{document}
  \input{input1}
  \input{input2}
  \end{document}
  ```

The following simulates your scenario. Compile it with `-shell-escape`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

% creating a package
\begin{filecontents*}{mypackage.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01] 
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}[2013/05/01 v0.01 LaTeX package for my own purpose]
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
% put other packages here
\endinput
\end{filecontents*}

% creating the first input file
\begin{filecontents*}{input1.tex}
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mypackage}
\begin{document}
Karl's students do not care about arrow tips.
\[
E \ne mc^2
\]
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

% creating the second input file
\begin{filecontents*}{input2.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mypackage}
\begin{document}
Karl's students do not care about dashing patterns.
\[
pV = nRT
\]
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

% creating the main input file
\begin{filecontents*}{main.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mypackage}
\usepackage{docmute}

\begin{document}
\input{input1}
\input{input2}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\immediate\write18{pdflatex main}
please open \url{main.pdf}
\end{document}
```

### Notes

Some people use the combination of `standalone` document class and package. And some other people use the combination of `subfiles` document class and package.

But I believe my method above is much more flexible than these two methods because the included input files can make use of any document class.

Comment: @doncherry: Upvoting this answer will get it up to 17 rep!

Comment: Sure, but I read neither the question nor the answer, so I won’t blindly upvote `;)`

Comment: Oh my ghost, I redo what I did but now it is 1 rep higher.

Answer (score 2):

use the documentclass `combine` if you want to create a new document which combines several other TeX documents. Run `texdoc combine` to get the documentation for `combine`

Comment: @Herbert can you show your answer with an example. I don,t know what is 'texdoc combine'.

Comment: You'll get the documentation of _every_ class or package when running `texdoc <name>` in a terminal or command window