# TeXnicCenter project - Print to separate chapter pdf

Tags: pdf, texniccenter

I have a project that includes 2 chapters and when I compile the main program it combines the pdf's of these two into one single file. How can I configure it to print to separate pdf's ?

Comment: That's just how it is. You can't configure (La)TeX to produce two separate PDFs.

Comment: ...for example, see [Splitting(!) one LaTeX document into two PDF outputs including references](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/157083/5764) where the suggestion is to make two "equivalent" files `full.tex` (say `fullA.tex` and `fullB.tex`) which you compile independently in order to produce two separate outputs. However, this is essentially the same as "one input > one output" and not "one input > two outputs".

Comment: Why not just use [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit) to split the output in two?

Comment: When I had a similar requirement - to produce a PDF with n chapters, and n PDFs each with one chapter - I used a perl script that I called from Build/Define Output Profiles/Postprocessor. It's possible my script used pdftk, I don't recall.

Comment: @Werner That Link really helped. I think that's the optimum way of achieving what I required.