# How to include a *.tex file in another one when each use their own classes

Tags: document-classes, input, pdfpages, include

I have two *.tex files (let say main.tex and subtex.tex). I want to include the "subtex" in the main file. The accepted answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155867/making-one-pdf-file-from-multiple-pdfs-or-tex) might work but the problem is that the "subtex.tex" use its own class (\documentclass[letterpaper]{myclass.cls}) so I cannot use

```
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}
```

in the "subtex". any other method that can help?

Comment: you can use the pdfpages package to include one pdf into another but then the included file keeps all its formatting and page numbers etc. usually it is not hard to simply use \input` of the body of the document without its preamble and arrange that you define all the commands necessary in the preamble of the main document, so that you get a consistent formatting across the combined document/

Comment: Is there any way they *could* be made to use the same preamble? If not, pdfpages sounds best. Or `\addtocounter{page}{?}` and inserting the other document pages by hand -- Oh the good old days!